# Pattern matching in instanceof is not supported in version 6. Please I’m trying to catch duplicate entry error in jsp servlet

Tags: java, servlets

Please I’m trying to catch duplicate entry error in jsp servlet.
Here is my code

```
Insert Ignore into(…)
catch(SQLException E){
if(e instanceof SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e){
message= “Warning: “ + e.getMessage();
}
}
```

Comment: Hopefully you do not talk about java 6 if you wirte `version 6`

Comment: BTW you should not catch a parent class and than use instance of, you should only catch the sub class in a separate catch block `catch( SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e){message= “Warning: “ + e.getMessage();
}catch(SQLException e){ //dosomething else
}
}`

Comment: And where you want pattern matching?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I did but the duplicate entry error not displaying after changing insert to insert ignore

Comment: I am using insert ignore but I still want to see those duplicate that were ignored

Comment: It says Source version 6 not supported use source 16 or higher is this talking about Java?

Comment: I think I should let my problem be a little clearer

Comment: Just developed a web app to insert users data from excel the app works fine but when data was inserted and it catch duplicate error MySQL stops operation, I tried solving the problem using insert ignore but the duplicate entry warning   is not showing  but if I insert direct from workbench I get the error

Answer (score 0):

```
} catch (SQLException e) {
    if (e instanceof SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException) {
        message = “Warning: “ + e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Or more honest about wiping an exception under the carpet:

```
} catch (SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e) {
    message = “Warning: “ + e.getMessage();
} catch (SQLException e2) {
}
```

You do not need a SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException variable.
And you might have casted it as

```
 ((SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException)e).getMessage()
```

Comment: Tried this but I don’t get any warning message after using insert ignore

Comment: Also add `message = “Warning2: “ + e2.getMessage();` for `e2` if you are using that variant.

Comment: I think I will need a jdbc method to show that warning because no warning or error from MySQL

Comment: Mostly helps debugging, and also trying the SQL string produced in a separate tool. It must be something silly if no SQL exception is thrown.

Comment: This is my problem if a different solution exist
Just developed a web app to insert users data from excel the app works fine but when data was inserted and it catch duplicate error MySQL stops operation, I tried solving the problem using insert ignore but the duplicate entry warning   is not showing  but if I insert direct from workbench I get the error

Comment: Ask an other question with the code and SQL statement. Normally JDBC is rock solid (> 30 years experience). I would even say, when nothing seems to help, write a small test program with just that code.

Comment: Unfortunately the system doesn’t allow me to ask another question today